# divs being messed up when using relative position and using the auto center method

Tags: html

i am trying to get my site to auto center a div that has a bunch of divs inside of it on the page by using a set width and defining a margin of 0 auto; if i set my inner div elements to absolute positioning everything lines up properly but it doesn't auto center, but if i set the positioning to relative the inner divs stack on top of each other in the correct horizontal position but not the vertical. so my question is what do i need to do to get my page to auto center while maintaining the correct relative positioning.

sample code:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="Table_01" align="center">
<div id="layout-01_"> <img id="layout_01" src="images/layout_01.png" width="1060" height="11" alt="" /> </div>
<div id="layout-02_"> <img id="layout_02" src="images/layout_02.png" width="28" height="1489" alt="" /> </div>
<div id="layout-03_"> <img id="layout_03" src="images/layout_03.png" width="279" height="65" alt="" /> </div>
<div id="layout-04_"> <img id="layout_04" src="images/layout_04.png" width="753" height="4" alt="" /> </div>
<div id="layout-05_"> <img id="layout_05" src="images/layout_05.png" width="599" height="1" alt="" /> </div>
</div>
</div>


div.container {
    width: 1060px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#Table_01 {
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:1060px;
    height:1500px;
    text-align: center;

}

#layout-01_ {
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:1060px;
    height:11px;
}

#layout-02_ {
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:11px;
    width:28px;
    height:1489px;
}

#layout-03_ {
    position:relative;
    left:28px;
    top:11px;
    width:279px;
    height:65px;
}

#layout-04_ {
    position:relative;
    left:307px;
    top:11px;
    width:753px;
    height:4px;
}

#layout-05_ {
    position:relative;
    left:307px;
    top:15px;
    width:599px;
    height:1px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: a few basics about positioning. You have two options.

1. Use `position: relative` with `float: left` on each of the layout divs, or;
2. Use `position: absolute` with `left: xyzpx` and `top: xyzpx`. Make sure to put keep the `position: relative` in the #Table_01 class. Absolutely position elements will be positioned relative to the top left corner of the first ancestor where the position is set to anything other than static. Refer to http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp for more information on positioning.

For centring, apply a width (any unit), `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` to the parent div. This will centre that div. Any children will not be centred. Which element, exactly, is it that you want centred? .container or #Table_01?

On another note, unless you absolutely **know** what size screens your viewers are going to be using, I recommend you use percentages instead of pixels. If the user, like myself, has a 1920 by 1080 screen, it is going to look awefully funny if it is only 1060px or something. If you set it to 80% with margin-left / right set to auto then there will only be 10% on either side. I usually tend to go for 60 or 70% myself.

Edit: One thing I neglected to mention - if using the relative / float: left method, whenever you want to put the remaining content below previous content, place a div with clear: both after that content.

For example:

```
<div style="width: 25%; float: left;">quarter of the width</div>
<div style="width: 50%; float: left;">half of the width</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
Extra content
```

This will generate two "columns", one at 25% and one at 50% of the parent containers width. The phrase "Extra content" will appear below the longest column. For example if one is 3 lines and the other is 5 lines, this phrase will appear 6 lines down.

Comment: i want .container to be centered

Comment: ok so you apply `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` to that then. Let me know if its what you're looking for.

Comment: that doesn't change anything, the child divs are still stacking on each other.

Comment: you need to apply one of the two methods I listed before that too. I am thinking you need position: absolute with the left and top attributes specified. However if you look here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/BS89n/ it looks funny. Are you able to draw what layout you want, then put the picture up here? By the way I applied the margin-left and -right, and the result is that, on a window wider than 1060px, outer div is centred.

Comment: okay i got it now, i also needed to set the div.container to position:relative; to make it auto center.

Comment: cool cool. So all the child divs are laying out correctly, yeah?

Answer (score 0):

Try relative on the parent and absolute for the children. And have some content that isn't absolutely positioned inside, possibly add a min-height.

Ideally you don't want to use AP though, for everything.